# scikit learn coefficients polynomialfeatures

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have fit a model with the help of PolynomialFeatures, but I don't know how to grab the coefficients of the model. The code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.matrix([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]).reshape((11,1))
Y = np.matrix([0,2.2,3.5,14.3,20.4,32.1,40.3,  
           59.1,86.2,90.3,99.9]).reshape((11,1))
a = PolynomialFeatures(15)
modelo = make_pipeline(a, LinearRegression())
modelo.fit(X, Y)
plt.plot(X,Y,'.')
plt.plot(X, modelo.predict(X),'-')
plt.show()
```

[image: original data]

Answer (score 21):

Let's begin by using a second degree polynomial, instead of 15 degree polynomial in your example, to simplify your problem (as well as to avoid overfitting).

[image: Second Degree Polynomial fit]

Using your X let's see how the values are transformed.

```
a = PolynomialFeatures(2)
a.fit_transform(X)

array([[   1.,    0.,    0.],
       [   1.,    1.,    1.],
       [   1.,    2.,    4.],
       [   1.,    3.,    9.],
       [   1.,    4.,   16.],
       [   1.,    5.,   25.],
       [   1.,    6.,   36.],
       [   1.,    7.,   49.],
       [   1.,    8.,   64.],
       [   1.,    9.,   81.],
       [   1.,   10.,  100.]])
```

We can see that the first feature is `X^0`, second is `X^1`, third is `X^2`.

Now, using your existing code, you are building a pipeline of two steps as `modelo`.

We are able to access the second step's estimator using `modelo.steps[1][1]`. From there we can use `coef_` to obtain the coefficients, and `intercept_` to obtain the intercept.

```
modelo.steps[1][1].coef_
# [[ 0.          3.3486014   0.76468531]]

modelo.steps[1][1].intercept_
# [-2.75244755]
```

From here we can see that the polynomial is 
`y_estimated = -2.75 + 0 * X^0 + 3.35 * X^1  + 0.76 * X^2`

Comment: It seems to me that model.coef_[0] will always be 0.0, with the actual intercept being clf.intercept_, have you found this to be the case in your experience? Is there any documentation you know of to confirm this?

Comment: Yes. That is my experience for a `LinearRegression` model. It may vary depending on what sklearn estimator is used.

Comment: You can either include the bias in the features:
`make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree, include_bias=True),LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False))`
Or in the Linear regression:
`make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree, include_bias=False),LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True))`. By default both are `True` and the first `coef_` is then always zero.