# Coefficient in support vector regression (SVR) using grid search (GridSearchCV) and Pipeline in Scikit Learn

Tags: regression, svm, python, scikit-learn

I am having trouble to access the coefficients of a support vector regression model (SVR) in scikit learn when the model is embedded in a pipeline and a grid search.
Consider the following example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

iris = load_iris()
X_train = iris.data
y_train = iris.target

clf = SVR(kernel='linear')
select = SelectKBest(k=2)
steps = [('feature_selection', select), ('svr', clf)]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)
grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid={"svr__C":[10,10,100],"svr__gamma": np.logspace(-2, 2)})
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

This seems to work fine but when I try to access the coefficient of the best fitting model

```
grid.best_estimator_.coef_
```

I get an error message: AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'coef_'.

I also tried to access the individual steps of the pipeline:

```
pipeline.named_steps['svr']
```

but could not find the coefficients there.

Answer (score 3):

Just happened to come across the same problem and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373606/scikit-learn-coefficients-polynomialfeatures)
had the answer:
`grid.best_estimator_` contains an instance of the pipeline, which consists of `steps`. The last step should always be the estimator, so you should always find the coefficients at:

`grid.best_estimator_.steps[-1][1].coef_`