# Multivariate polynomial regression for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

In extension of: [scikit learn coefficients polynomialfeatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373606/scikit-learn-coefficients-polynomialfeatures)

What is a straightforward way of doing multivariate polynomial regression for python?

Say, we have N samples with each 3 features and we have for each sample 40 (may as well be any number, of course, but it is 40 in my case) response variables. We want to make a function that relates the 3 independent variables to the 40 response variables. For this, we train a polynomial model on N-1 of our samples, and estimate the 40 response variables of the remaining one sample. The dimensionalities of independent variable (X) and response variable (y) training and test data:

```
X_train = [(N-1) * 3], y_train = [(N-1) * 40], X_test = [1 * 3], y_test = [1 * 40]
```

As I would expect, such an approach should yield:

```
y = intercept + a x1 + b x1^2 + c x2 + d x2^2 + e x3 + f x3^3 + g x1 x2 + h x1 x3 + i x2 x3
```

Which is a total of 9 coefficients plus one intercept for every sample to describe the polynomial. If I use the method proposed earlier by David Maust in 2015:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.pipeline import *

model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree=2),LinearRegression())
y_poly = model.fit(X_train,y_train)

coefficients = model.steps[1][1].coef_
intercepts = model.steps[1][1].intercept_

coefficients.shape

[Output: (40, 10)]
```

For every response variable, it appears we end up with 10 coefficients + one intercept, which is one more coefficient than I would expect. Therefore it is unclear to me what these coefficients mean and how to make up the polynomial that describes our response variable. I really hope StackOverflow could help me out! Hopefully I defined my problem well enough.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out there are 9 coefficients and a bias term after the polynomial transformation. However when you pass this N by 10 matrix to sklearn's `LinearRegression` this is interpreted as a 10 dimensional dataset. In addition, by default, sklearn fits the regression line with an intercept, therefore you have 10 coefficients and one intercept. I think the first coefficient will most likely be 0 though (at least that is what I obtained after testing my answers below with the data from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373606/scikit-learn-coefficients-polynomialfeatures)).

To get your expected behaviour I think you have two options:

1. disable the bias term in `PolynomialFeatures`.

`model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree=2,include_bias=False), LinearRegression())`

2. tell `LinearRegression` not to fit an intercept, and instead your first coefficient (coefficient of the bias term) will be the intercept. In this case your intercept is `model.steps[1][1].coef_[0]`.

`model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree=2), LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False))`

I hope this helps! Out of curiosity what is the value you get for `model.steps[1][1].coef_[0]`?

Comment: Hi gf712, thanks a lot for your input!

I considered your suggestions, and through this method it indeed yields one less regression coefficient for every response variable. I think this is one step in the right direction to solve my problem, but I am still uncertain how I actually obtain the polynomial. In other words, which of these coefficients corresponds to which feature?

To answer your question, model.steps[1][1].coef_[0] yields a 1x10 list of 0's. Likely because there is no variability in my first response variable (the same for all N samples)  (?)

Comment: Save a reference to the `PolynomialFeatures` object (e.g. `pf = PolynomialFeatures(...)`, then later you can call `print(pf.poly.get_feature_names())`.