# Get the coefficients of my sklearn polynomial regression model in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to get the coefficients of my sklearn polynomial regression model in Python so I can write the equation elsewhere.. i.e. ax1^2 + ax + bx2^2 + bx2 + c

I've looked at the answers elsewhere but can't seem to get the solution, unless I just don't know what I am looking at.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 2)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X_train)
lin_reg_2 = LinearRegression()
lin_reg_2.fit(X_poly,y_train)

lin_reg_2.coef_
```

Comment: Have you checked [scikit learn coefficients polynomialfeatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373606/scikit-learn-coefficients-polynomialfeatures) for example

Comment: I have, but I am not using the make_pipeline library so I have no .steps method to use...

Answer (score 2):

You were so close. The problem is how you wrote the model. For it to work you'll have to write it as:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 2)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X_Train)
lin_reg_2=LinearRegression().fit(X_poly, y_Train)
pred = lin_reg_2.predict(X_poly_test) #this line is not necessary. It's just a predict for test data

lin_reg_2.coef_
```

Also make sure X_train and y_train are arrays with the right shapes.

Comment: If your fit does not go through the origin (0,0) use lin_reg_2.intercept_ to get the y-interception. [For scikit the y-interception apparently does not belong to the coefficients. It depends on the mathematical definition of the polynomial fit. I have seen functions of the form y = a_0*x^0 + a_1*x^1 + a_2*x^2 ... or in general y = sum (a_i*x^i) with the polynomial degree i. With that understanding of a polynomial also the y-intercept (a_0) is a coefficient. So, if you are looking for whole set, you have to include the value for the y-intercept of the scikit definition.]

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should work, it was taken from my own script :

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
poly_x_inliers = poly_reg.fit_transform(x_inliers)

regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(poly_x_inliers, y_inliers)

reg_label = "Inliers coef:%s - b:%0.2f" % \
            (np.array2string(regressor.coef_,
                             formatter={'float_kind': lambda fk: "%.3f" % fk}),
            regressor.intercept_)
print(reg_label)
```

You should check on : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

Answer (score -1):

Support Vector Regression:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import numpy as np
n_samples, n_features = 10, 5
np.random.seed(0)
y = np.random.randn(n_samples)
X = np.random.randn(n_samples, n_features)
clf = SVR(kernel="poly",degree=3,gamma="scale",C=0.8)
clf.fit(X, y) 
clf.predict(X)
```

Definition of class sklearn.svm.SVR：

```
class sklearn.svm.SVR(kernel=’rbf’, degree=3, gamma=’auto_deprecated’, coef0=0.0, tol=0.001, C=1.0, epsilon=0.1, shrinking=True, cache_size=200, verbose=False, max_iter=-1)
```